# How can we integrate PHP web application with Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: php, outlook

I want to create an option in the website for add appointments with date and time to my outlook calendar from the website using php. How can we integrate PHP web application with Microsoft Outlook?

Also Appointment date should be send as a request in the email send from the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to do it simply sending a mail to your email, 
appointments information is send as a ics file.

in gmail when a ics file is revised it reads the data in the ics file and add event to the google calendar.

so you will be able to get the job done simply by an email, you will have to read about ics file and get the syntax of it.

sample ics file looks like

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
                  VERSION:2.0
                  BEGIN:VEVENT
                  STATUS:TENTATIVE
                  DTSTART:"+NewStartDate+"T"+NewStartTime+"Z
                 DTEND:"+NewEndDate+"T"+NewEndTime+"Z
                 LOCATION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:"+Location+"
                  CATEGORIES:Profissional
                 DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:"+Description+"
                  SUMMARY;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:"+Subject+"
                  PRIORITY:3
                  END:VEVENT
                  END:VCALENDAR
```

I found this when i google, hope this will help
https://gist.github.com/jakebellacera/635416